# LibGdx Textbutton Listener

Tags: java, libgdx

Im completly new here and I need some fast help on a Project!!

I use LibGdx to write a little "Risiko" if somebody know it. Im creating a menu and my TextButtons dont work!! Here is the important Part:

```
stage = new Stage[3];
    stage[0] = new Stage();
    stage[1]= new Stage();
    stage[2]= new Stage();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    setBmap(new Texture("map.png"));

    inputMultiplexer=new InputMultiplexer();
    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(this);

    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage[0]);
    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage[1]);
    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage[2]);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);
    button = new TextButton[8];
    //Southamerica
    button[0] = new TextButton("Attack", textButtonStyle);
    button[0].setBounds(605,463, 100,40);
```

... Create the buttons.

```
    stage[0].addActor(button[0]);
    stage[0].addActor(button[1]);
    stage[0].addActor(button[2]);
    stage[1].addActor(button[4]);
    stage[1].addActor(button[5]);
    stage[1].addActor(button[6]);
    stage[2].addActor(button[3]);
    stage[2].addActor(button[7]);

    for(int i= 0; i <= 7 ; i++){
        button[i].addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
                System.out.println("Button action");
            }});
        }
    /*button[0].addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            System.out.println("BUTTOn");
        }
    });*/
        button[0].addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
                System.out.println("BUTTON PRESSED!!");
            }});
```

Add Buttons to stages and create the Listener!

And now my render() :

```
    super.render();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   

    font = new BitmapFont();
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(getBmap(), 0, 0);
    stage[0].draw();

    -
        batch.end();     
    }
```

I use different Stages do draw different menus. Just for Info :D

And already Thanks for any answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for the request now I got it. I didnt got that I have to do it like this:

```
inputMultiplexer=new InputMultiplexer();
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage[0]);
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage[1]);
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage[2]);
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(this);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);
```

and not like this:

```
inputMultiplexer=new InputMultiplexer();
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(this);
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage[0]);
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage[1]);
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage[2]);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);
```

I love it :D
RIP